# MVC:replacing HTML.ActionLink with ahref

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, anchor, actionlink

Earlier I had `ActionLink`

```
 <%: Html.ActionLink("Add Race", "AddRace", 
          new {eventId = Model.EventId,fleetId=Model.SelectedFleet.ID}) %>
```

on my page..and it is working fine. But now my requirement is it must check if some there is some data in `FooEntity` then it redirect to another view otherwise it should display an `alert` message..

so i changed `ActionLink` to `ahref` and thinking to use `$.ajax` call with it..but my action `AddRace` is written accordingly `ActionLink`. but now i'm using `ahref` so i want to make ajaxcall which will return some `boolean` and based on that i'll redirect or show `alert`. I need to re-write `AddRace Action`. I'm pretty new to `MVC` so confuse in changing my `AddRace` action.

`ahref`:

```
 <a href="#" onclick='checkFleetAddedandScroing()'>Add Race</a>
```

`Action` is:

```
 public ActionResult AddRace(Guid eventId, Guid fleetId)
    {
        try
        {
            var model = new RaceModel { EventID = eventId, FleetID = fleetId, IsAddPHRFBFactors = IsAddPhrfbFactors(eventId, fleetId) };
            SetFleetsInViewBagForAddRace(eventId);
            return View(model);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {                
            throw;
        }            
    }
```

Please suggest me how to do it....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the same parameters.

```
<a href="#" onclick='checkFleetAddedandScroing("<%= Url.Action("AddRace", 
    new {eventId = Model.EventId,fleetId=Model.SelectedFleet.ID}  %>")'>Add Race</a>
```

EDIT:

You don't even need to do an a tag.

```
 <%: Html.ActionLink("Add Race", "AddRace", 
      new {eventId = Model.EventId,fleetId=Model.SelectedFleet.ID}, 
      new {onclick="return myFunction()"}) %>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction() {
        return confirm("Click no to cancel the navigation, otherwise click yes");
    }
</script>
```

Then you would do your ajax call in the javascript function and return false when you want to cancel redirect.

Comment: thanks for quick response..but i'm confused in as `ActionLink` could directly redirect me to view..but in this case redirection will be optional. like if some relative data is present is `FooEntity` then only redirect otherwise it must show an alert and return false..That's what i'm confusing in writing and in changing `Action` according to this requirement..

Comment: @MayankPathak - then why did your post have an a tag with different parameters?

Comment: sorry, that's my mistake in asking question..that will be just a function..I've edited my question..that `js` function will make ajax call and based on bool result i have to either redirect or show an alert..

Comment: its still navigating even it i click cancel...'

Comment: @MayankPathak - see my update, add the return keyword in the onclick